# PHP calling Graphdb works in shell, not in browser

Tags: php, azure, docker, graph

How come, this little stunt gets the expected output in the shell, but not within the browser?
Here you have the details.
I want to read from a Graph-DB on CosmosDB within my Azure subscription from out of a Ubuntu Docker through PHP with the Brightzone lib within any common web browser.
Essencially
**Not working** :         GraphDB->CosmosDB->Azure->Docker->Ubuntu->PHP->Brightzone->**Browser**
Perfectly **working** : GraphDB->CosmosDB->Azure->Docker->Ubuntu->PHP->Brightzone->**Shell**

My Ubuntu Docker setup:

```
docker image pull ubuntu
docker run -it -p 80:80 -v /<localpath>/httpVolume:/var/www/html ubuntu /bin/bash

apt install apache2 
apt install php libapache2-mod-php
apt install git
apt install php7.2-mbstring
apt install curl

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

cd /var/www/html/

echo "{" > composer.json
echo -e '    "require": {' >> composer.json
echo -e '        "brightzone/gremlin-php": "3.*"' >> composer.json
echo -e "    }" >> composer.json
echo -e "}" >> composer.json

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer install

php composer.phar require brightzone/gremlin-php "3.*"
```

My PHP file is very much taken from the Microsoft sample.
`git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-php-getting-started`
The PHP file :

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>test</title>
    </header>

    <body>
    <?php
        require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
        use \Brightzone\GremlinDriver\Connection;

        $db = new Connection([
            'host' => '<Resourcename>.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com',
            'username' => '/dbs/<graphdatabasename>/colls/<MySillyTestCollection>',
            'password' => '<prettyLongAzureKey>'
            ,'port' => '443'

            // Required parameter
            ,'ssl' => TRUE
        ]);

        try {

            $db->timeout = 0.5; 

            $db->open();

            if($db){
                $query = "g.V().count()";
                printf("\t%s\n\tQuery: %s\n", "Counting all the vertices.\n", $query);
                $result = $db->send($query);

                if($result) {
                    printf("\tNumber of vertices in this graph: %s\n\n", $result[0]);
                }
            } else {
                echo "Can't open DB";
            }

            $db->close();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the fun part.
It works when executing it from the shell. `php index.php`
And it will give me: `Number of vertices in this graph: 4`
Any browser, within the Docker container or from the host, will **not** show me the expected and very much desired 4, but rather print the called function `g.V().count()`

Must I build my self a nasty work around and call exec()? I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Do you run the docker image in the Azure Ubuntu VM? And inside the VM, does it work perfectly?

Comment: Yep, it runs perfectly. I'm running it from my local machine. I have tried to run it in the Azure container service. Works the same way there. Just in shell, not in browser.

Comment: Do you mean the Azure Kubernetes service when you say Azure container service? Or the Azure Container instaince?

Comment: Never mind Azure/Cloud, I'm having the issue on my local machines running Docker locally. I'm hoping I'm missing some setting in PHP, or maybe the PHP script is wrong. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using ob_flush(); flush(); and ob_end_flush(); within my script.
Don't know why, and at this point I'm too afraid to ask.